# Insertion sort to make "year" of 0 top of list

Tags: c++, insertion-sort

I have an array of info on buildings, and one of the items is year built:

```
 buildingnumber[buildingsloaded].yearBuilt
```

I am trying to use insertion sort to sort the data from oldest built to newest built but it keeps reporting the same building for k. (k is how many buildings I want to see)

```
void InsertionSort(list buildingnumber[SIZE], int buildingsloaded)
{
int key = 0, i = 0;
    for(int j = 1; j < buildingsloaded; j++)
    {
        key=buildingnumber[j].yearBuilt;
        i=j-1;
        while(buildingnumber[i].yearBuilt > key && i >= 0)
        {
           buildingnumber[i+1] = buildingnumber[i];
           i--;
        }
        buildingnumber[i+1].yearBuilt = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `<algorithm>`'s `std::sort`?

Comment: hopefully this is for practice

Comment: what are you trying todo in "buildingnumber[i+1] = buildingnumber[i]" ? do you want to swap instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confused. You can write a sort that just compares a part of something (like `yearBuilt`) but when you actually do the sort you must move (or swap) the *whole object* not just the key.

So your code can be improved like this

```
     list b = buildingnumber[j]; // whole building
     key = b.yearBuilt;
     while (...)
     {
         ...
     }
     buildingnumber[i+1] = b;  // whole building
```

Not completely sure if now the code is correct (haven't checked) but at least you'll be a bit closer.

Another thing, why is your building object called `list`? Wouldn't `Building` be a better name? In code names matter **a lot**, and they are easy to change. If you can pick good names for your types and variables it shows you are thinking clearly about the problem. Don't skimp on this or think it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code contains an important error at

`while(buildingnumber[i].yearBuilt > key && i >= 0)`

because the conditions must be written in the contrary order:

`while (i >= 0 && buildingnumber[i].yearBuilt > key)`

The reason is that when `i<0`, you do not want to access `buildingnumber[i]` because that would access an invalid position of the array. Because `&&` will evaluate to `false` when the first operand is `false` without evaluating the second operand, in the correct way no invalid access is performed.

On the other hand, as noted in an other answer, the code does not order the hole `list` elements, just their key.

In addition, the `key` and `i` variables can be defined in smaller blocks.